# What is IV % actually measuring?

Tags: options, pricing

If the Implied IV of an option is 40%, what is the 40% representing, 40% of what?

Does that mean the underlying stock is estimated it may move up or down 40% in a day, month year?

The option price may move up/down 40%?

Its just an arbitrary number relative to other securities IV %?

Answer (score 1):

Implied volatility is the annualized standard deviation of the "lognormal return" of the underlying stock, implied by exchange traded options prices (utilizing the black scholes framework to price the option) for the time period of the expiration of the option.

So if you had a 40% implied vol for 1Yr IBM call options, the price of the call options are implying that if you took the daily log returns of IBM stock for a year, the standard deviation of those returns is 40%.  Volatility is annualized.

Comment: Hi Airacoon,  Thanks, so If I read that right the volatility of an option is a function of  the underlying asset and the historical vol. is factually arrived at whereas implied  vol. is a guess as to what is probable?

Comment: Historical vol will tell you how risky the underlying asset was. As Capital markets trade on a going forward basis, historical vol might inform where options price but the market will trade them, at any given time, on where it collectively believes the underlying volatility will be. The price of risk (defined as volatility) will fluctuate depending on the collective market perception of risk at that moment. IV is taking that particular price and imputing what that price implies the risk of the underlying asset will be.

Answer (score 0):

IV or implied volatility, when represented as a percentage, indicates the annualized expected one standard deviation range for the stock based on the option prices. For example, an IV of 40% on a \$200 stock would represent a one standard deviation range of \$80 over the next year.

When thinking of options as an insurance contract, the more risky it is means that the cost of insuring that risk becomes more expesive.

Basically its a way to compared the cost of the option from stock to stock without having to analyze the underlying cost of the option.